# What causes a "this connection is untrusted" issue?

Tags: security, http, ssl, https

I am new to development and at my new job we have this issue where on a sub-domain users are getting the error you see below but when they go to the base domain (e.g: domain.com) they don't see that.

I am supposed to solve this but not sure what might be causing it.  I am not looking for somebody to solve this for me but if you can outline possible reasons why, i would be very thankful.

[image]

Comment: This is off topic for SO, but since you're here: the certificate you have installed on your domain is specific to that domain. It's not acting for the subdomains, but the subdomains are getting it through inheritnce. You can fi this by installing a wildcard certificate that will cover your subdomains as well.

Comment: For fixing the issue, you might also have a look at my answer on [How to disable “This Connection is Untrusted” Certificate in FireFox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709095/how-to-disable-this-connection-is-untrusted-certificate-in-firefox/37080038#37080038) Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing: open up the "Technical details". They will give you more information, information you might or might not yet fully understand, but it still have the necessary info.

Basically, SSL (https) certificates are created **for a specific domain**. If the domain name changes (from e.g. example.com to foo.example.com), the certificate can not be used without a security warning popping out.

You need to create (either by self-signing or purchasing) separate SSL certificates for all the host names/domains under which the site will be accepted, to avoid the security warning.  An alternate option is to purchase a wildcard certificate for the entire domain and sub tree (ie: *.example.com).

There are, to the best of my knowledge, no other ways around this; it's one part of how the HTTPS security is established.

Comment: Downvote, for what? I posted the answer first as slightly incomplete and then edited it to be more complete...

Comment: Upvoted! Your answer was complete and so descriptive.

Comment: Certs are created for a specific name, not a specific server. A single cert can be installed on multiple servers for load-balanced websites. Also, wildcard and multi-name certs are common.

Comment: @PerLundberg: I updated your answer.  You were wrong on a few details although overall your answer was good

Comment: @Joe: good points. "Host name" and "server" aren't always equivalent, even though they foten correlate.

Comment: @Chris: thanks! Good edit. Wasn't aware of wildcard entries, but they sound like a quite good alternative in this case.

Answer (score 1):

When you're running HTTPS, you should have a different certificate for each server (subdomain) not each domain and the client should trust it if you don't want them to see this error.

You can use a wildcard certificate also. It would inherit through all subdomains.

Comment: Likewise, who is the chicken who downvoted this without explaining why...? :P

Comment: Server and subdomain are not interchangeable terms. Wildcard certs allow for one cert to be attached to multiple subdomains of the same domain.